# Setting and environment variable for one specific subdomain matching the ServerAlias

Tags: apache2, dns, virtualhost, apache

I have a virtual host that includes the following settings

```
ServerName www.host.com
ServerAlias *.host.com
```

Can I set

```
SetEnv FOO "bar"
```

for just a specific subdomain (like `foo.host.com`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the `SetEnvIf` directive:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*foo\.host\.com FOO=bar
```